# Is it true that ${(\bar Z)^2} = \overline {({Z^2})} $?

Tags: calculus

Let $Z\in \Bbb C$.

Is it true that ${(\bar Z)^2} = \overline {({Z^2})} $?

Comment: Yes, it is ture.

Comment: why don't you try yourself instead of asking the question ?

Comment: @user1952009 - I'm sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, if $z,w\in\mathbb C$, then $\overline{z}\cdot \overline{w}=\overline{z\cdot w}$.

Proof: Let $z=a+ib$, $w=c+id$ for some $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb R$.

$$z\cdot w=(ac-bd)+i(ad+bc)$$ The following is called a [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity):

$$\left(a^2+b^2\right)\left(c^2+d^2\right)=(ac-bd)^2+(ad+bc)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because more generally, $\overline z\cdot\overline w=\overline{z\cdot w}$.

Answer (score 0):

Very good answer from user236182, and I like this one as well:

$z=\alpha e^{i\theta}$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$; $w=\beta e^{i\psi}$

$z\cdot w=\alpha\beta e^{i(\theta+\psi)}$

You take the conjugate very easily that way and show that $\overline z\cdot\overline w=\overline{z\cdot w}$